# Return to Locked screen after launching activity from background

Tags: android

I have a service running in the background which launches an activity. If the keyguard and lock screen are on I use the following flags in the onCreate of the lauched activity to show it above the keyguard and lock screen

```
 getWindow().addFlags(
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |      
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                );
```

However when the activity is dismissed I want it to go back to the lock screen, it is instead returning to the keyguard. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` param?